# Рисование дисковых диаграмм

Tags: java, javafx, диаграммы

В старом оборудовании используется диаграммный диск Р-2212. Есть регистрирующий прибор, сохраняющий данные в CSV-файл(время и температуру, разрешение секунда, общее время - пару дней). Подскажите, как реализовать такую диаграмму?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Распарсить и построить диаграмму ?) Что может парситься проще, чем csv?

Comment: http://www.teploautomatica.ru/sites/default/files/styles/medium-copy-1/public/device_image/r_2190.jpg?itok=jcXc9rsH